# How to use VirtualizingStackPanel CleanUpVirtualizedItemEvent?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, c++-cx

I've customised the style of a ListBox in order to register for the `VirtualizingStackPanel.CleanUpVirtualizedItemEvent`. I need to free up some memory when the item is re-virtualized, and then re-load the memory when it is un-virtualized. Whenever I check to see if the item is virtualized, it always returns false:

`const bool isVirtualizing = VirtualizingStackPanel::GetIsVirtualizing(e->UIElement); // Always returns false`

How do I work with this event? I can change the `ListBox` to use `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"` but that causes the UI to be created and deleted constantly, which can lead to performance issues. I'd rather recycle the UI controls if possible.

Comment: Which platform are you using? WPF doesn't support C++ so is this about a WinRT Window Store XAML App? The Windows-RT tag is for the ARM version of Windows 8 so is your issue specific to ARM?

Comment: C++/CX & Windows Runtime. I've updated the tag. It should be the same in WPF as it is in WinRT.

Comment: There is no WPF in WinRT. They just call it XAML, XAML UI or WinRT/XAML. The old code name was "Jupiter".

Comment: VirtualizationMode="Recycling" isn't available in winrt?

Comment: Filip, I know what WPF is, I was just saying the solution should be the same.

Comment: Chris, Recycling is available.